# Cloning inherited record

Tags: c#-9.0

I want to benefit both from the built-in cloning functionality of the record construct in c#, and from its extensibility. Based on [this article](https://dev.to/wrijugh/c-9-0-inheritance-in-record-type-ffi), I have:

```
public record Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public record Student : Person
{
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

These work:

```
var person = new Person() { FullName = "Wrishika Ghosh" };
var student = new Student() { FullName = "Wrishika Ghosh", Grade = "V" };
```

I can also make a new `Person` from an existing `Person` using **`with`** a.k.a [non-destructive mutation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records#non-destructive-mutation). But can I make a new `Student` from an existing `Person` in a similar manner - without explicitly specifying all properties that could be cloned as they are inherited? I am looking for a semantics like this: `var student = new Student from person with { Grade = "V" }`